# How to publish sbt plugin to nexus repositories?

Tags: sbt, nexus

I am new to sbt plugin publishing and I have just rewrote some features of an exist plugin. It has been working locally sine I ran publish-local on sbt console. Now, I want publish it to nexus repositories.  Are there any good tutorial to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right now, publishing sbt-plugins to nexus repos can cause some issues, but generally, this should apply:  http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Using-Sonatype.html

Additionally, you want to make sure in your plugin's build.sbt file:

```
sbtPlugin := true

publishMavenStyle := true.
```

There are a few issue currently:

1. sbt-plugins are not legitimate maven artifacts, which is why most sbt plugins are published to "raw" repositories in this fashion: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Bintray-For-Plugins.html
2. Nexus, sometimes, will generate pom.xml files for ivy-deployed artifacts.  This can seriously mess with sbt's resolution.

That said, a few users are, and have been, successfully deploying plugins to maven central or nexus repositories.   We're actively working on sbt-ivy integration currently, so you will hopefully see more guidance in the nexus + sbt area soon.